# VisualStudioとgccで挙動が違うのはなぜですか？

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc

以下のプログラムをVisualStudio2017, wandbox(gcc) で実行すると異なる結果になります。
[wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GAcVt9qAAWz94YV7)

```
// This file is a "Hello, world!" in C++ language by GCC for wandbox.
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
namespace test {

    class Integer {
    public:
        explicit Integer() : value(0) {}
        int value;
    private:
    };

    class Data {
    public:
        explicit Data() = default;
        Integer i;
    private:
    };

    class Builder {
    public:
        explicit Builder() = default;
        Builder& set(Data& data) {
            data.i.value++;
            return *this;
        }
        Builder& print(std::vector<Data> vec) {
            for (Data data : vec)
                std::cout << data.i.value << std::endl;
            return *this;
        }
    private:
    };
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    test::Builder b;
    test::Data d;

    std::cout << d.i.value << std::endl;
    b.set(d).set(d).set(d).set(d).print(std::vector<test::Data>{d});
    return 0;
}
```

wandboxでは

```
0
4
```

と表示されますが、
VisualStudioでは

```
0
0
```

と表示されてしまいます。
なぜ挙動が違うのでしょうか？
どちらかのコンパイラの不具合ですか？

環境
VisualStudio
* VisualStudio Community 2017
* C++言語標準:ISO C++17 標準 (/std:c++17)

wandbox
* gcc HEAD 10.0.1 20200115 (experimental)
* 一つ下の 9.2.0 でも試しましたが同様の結果でした

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
b.set(d).set(d).set(d).set(d).print(std::vector<test::Data>{d});
```

この式を

```
auto s = b.set(d).set(d).set(d).set(d);
s.print(std::vector<test::Data>{d});
```

という順で評価して`4`を出力すべきか、

```
auto v = std::vector<test::Data>{d};
b.set(d).set(d).set(d).set(d).print(v);
```

という順で評価して`0`を出力すべきかはC++言語仕様では定められていないため、実装依存の結果となります。

C++17で[厳密な式の評価順](https://cpprefjp.github.io/lang/cpp17/expression_evaluation_order.html)を定めていますが、今回の部分の順序にはあえて触れられていないそうです。